# Matplotlib colourmap creating different images when using method .imsave() and .savefig()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been working on temperature maps and have been trying to save images using the matplotlib colourmap `viridis`. Originally, I was using the following code to create images and then save them:

```
# define normalisation and colourmap
norm = Normalize(vmin=2, vmax=42)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis').copy()
cmap.set_bad('white', 1.)

# apply colourmap to normalised data
map = cmap(norm(map))

# create and save figure
plt.imshow(map, cmap=cmap)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig(imgpath, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.cla()
```

This method was giving me the following image:
[result using plt.imshow() and plt.savefig()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIJTF.png)

I quickly noticed that `plt.savefig()` does not save the image with the original pixel resolution, but does so based on my screen resolution. So instead, I used plt.imsave, which preserves the original size of the array. Because `plt.imsave` doesn't have a flag for cmap, I applied it directly as follows:

```
plt.imsave(imgpath, arr=cmap(norm(map)), format='png')
```

However, using `plt.imsave` gave me a different map: [result using plt.imsave()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3I4b.png). The same thing happens when `cmap` is applied directly when using `plt.imshow()`

---

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I've tried with different maps from different areas, I'm sure that I've been using exactly the same instance of the colourmap and normalisation on both methods.

Can anyone tell me what the difference between the two methods is?

Comment: seems to me like you are applying your colormap twice with the first version. Once when you do `map = cmap(norm(map))`, and again when you run `plt.imshow(map, cmap=cmap)`. You probably want to just use the original `map` with `imshow`, and then use the `cmap` and `norm` kwargs

Comment: (side note, `map` is a [python built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), so is not a good choice for a variable name)

Comment: You're completely right about applying the colourmap twice - I adjusted my code and still get the same difference in images... (also, thanks for the sidenote - changed that as well!)